# Flash/Actionscript 3 - embedded sound play/stop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, playback

How do I play/stop an embedded music file in Flash/AS3 via a button?

This is what I have:

```
import flash.events.Event;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;  
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var myMusic:Sound = new ThemeSong(); 
var channel:SoundChannel = myMusic.play();

startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartClick);
stopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStopClick);

function onStartClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myMusic.play();
}

function onStopClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myMusic.stop();
}
```

ThemeSong is the name of the class I assigned for the music file (import -> libraries -> properties -> export for AS -> class name). startButton and stopButton are the identifiers for the buttons.

If I run this I'll get an error saying:

```
"Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 69 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method stop through a reference with static type flash.media:Sound."
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close Flash is wonky sometimes:

```
import flash.events.Event;  
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.MovieClip;  
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;

var myMusic:Sound = new ThemeSong(); 
var channel:SoundChannel = myMusic.play();

startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStartClick);
stopButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onStopClick);

function onStartClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    channel = myMusic.play();
}

function onStopClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
    channel.stop();
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html#stop()

Comment: believe play method takes a time, so you when you stop you have to record how long it's already been playing for then call play with that time (it's sort of a pain)